# Dynamically changing form is Symfony 5

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony5

I am trying to make a form that changes based on user response, I have a ChoiceType::class for the first part with 'yes' or 'no' as the options. If the user selects 'yes' I want the second part of the form to show up to get their response to that, but if they select 'no' I just want to keep that second form hidden.

This is the form I have so far

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  ->add('attending', ChoiceType::class, [
     'choices' => [
       'yes' => true,
       'no' => false,
     ],
     'attr' => [
        'class' => 'attendanceStatus'
     ],
     'mapped' => false,
     'required' => true,
     'label' => 'Will you be attending?',
     'placeholder' => 'Please make selection',
  ])
  ->add('bringingGuest', ChoiceType::class, [
     'choices' => [
       'yes' => true,
       'no' => false,
     ],
```

I wrapped the forms in a class and gave each form an ID

```
    <div class="attendance">
      <div id="attendance-status">
        {{ form_label(form.attending) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.attending) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.attending) }}
      </div>
      <div id="guest" style="display: none;">
        {{ form_label(form.bringingGuest) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.bringingGuest) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.bringingGuest) }}
      </div>
</div>
```

I'm not the greatest with javascript but I tried to do an if statement like this

```
if ('.attending' == true) {
 document.getElementById('guest').style.display = 'block';
}
```

I've been at this for a bit of time now and I can't seem to figure out how to do it properly. I thought it would be something like having an event listener for the user selection and then just using javascript to show the second form if conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

This is, like you probably already know, a javascript question. Like you said, you can use an event listener, for example to run a function whenever a value changes. Here's an example:

```js
const someId = document.getElementById('some-id');
const example = document.getElementById('example');

someId.addEventListener('change', doSomething);

function doSomething() {
  if (someId.value === "yes") {
    example.innerHTML = "YES!"
  } else {
    example.innerHTML = ""
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="name" id="some-id">
  <option value="no">no</option>
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
</select>

<div id="example">
</div>
```

All you need to do is check what IDs you should target and what you want to happen on which event. To find out more about events, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events.

Comment: But how would something like this work when the form isn't coming from HTML, its from Symfony? Wouldn't I need to call the Symfony class not the html element because I don't believe they overlap with eachother.

Comment: Your PHP code (using Symfony) generates HTML. You can inspect this HTML in your browser and use the IDs of the generated fields (or wrap them in another element) to target them.

Comment: Would this require a submit button or would it happen the moment they make their selection from the drop down?

Comment: When you add an event listener, you can listen for any event, such as a change, focus, select, submit, etc... So no, it does not require a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) page in Symfony docs.
In your case it will be [Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) section.

It involves 2 types of events - Form events on PHP/Symfony side and JS mostly "passive" role to listen for element change and replace the HTML.

The idea is next:

- On user action on the HTML element send a request to backend and render the new state for the page based on the element's changed value. Here you get full page HTML as a response.
- Then just replace dependent chunks of the page with the new rendered pieces of HTML you get from the response.

Here are main parts (copy-pasted from the docs):

```php
// src/Form/Type/SportMeetupType.php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Position;
use App\Entity\Sport;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
// ...

class SportMeetupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('sport', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Sport::class,
                'placeholder' => '',
            ])
        ;

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Sport $sport = null) {
            $positions = null === $sport ? [] : $sport->getAvailablePositions();

            $form->add('position', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Position::class,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $positions,
            ]);
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getSport());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('sport')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $sport = $event->getForm()->getData();

                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $sport);
            }
        );
    }

    // ...
}
```

in JS:

```js
{# templates/meetup/create.html.twig #}
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.sport) }}    {# <select id="meetup_sport" ... #}
    {{ form_row(form.position) }} {# <select id="meetup_position" ... #}
    {# ... #}
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script>
var $sport = $('#meetup_sport');
// When sport gets selected ...
$sport.change(function() {
  // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
  var data = {};
  data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();
  // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
  $.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data : data,
    success: function(html) {
      // Replace current position field ...
      $('#meetup_position').replaceWith(
        // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
        $(html).find('#meetup_position')
      );
      // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
    }
  });
});
</script>
```